# multiple files drag and drop in webbrowser in c# winapp

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I am developing an application in which I need to drag and drop multiple files on the form,but I have one webbrowser in which I can do it for only one document using it's navigating event.

Is there any way to allow multiple drag and drop using navigating event? if not then is there any way to over impose webbrowser's navigating by form's drag and drop? please provide solution if you have one.

I tried to solve it by doing form's allowdrop to true and webbrowser's `AllowWebBrowserDrop = true;` but, then also form's drag enter didn't fire..

Answer (score 0):

you can use  Ajax contorl toolkit AjaxFileUpload;

for more information: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

Comment: thank you..but it is for asp.net, iam developing winapp i.e c#.net can i use this in it?